how to pass variables into userForm without public variables?
i have a form to select path. I need pass variables to form and then back.
Is it possible without Public variables? (It works now with public variables).  Or how write it down correctly?
My try with local variables allways drop at "UserForm_Initialize".
main sub:
Sub test1()
    Dim cesta As String  'this variables
    Dim cesta2 As String
    
            cesta = "d:\path1\path2\path3\"
                cesta2 = "d:\path4\path5\path6\"
                        
                Call vyberCesty(cesta, cesta2) ' call form for path selection
                
                    If cesta = "" Then Exit Sub
End Sub

call form:
Sub vyberCesty(cesta As String, cesta2 As String)

    If Not f_FormIsLoaded("form_vyberCesty") Then
               Load form_vyberCesty()
               form_vyberCesty.Show
    End If

End Sub

form code:
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 'cesta As String, cesta2 As String) 'xxc
    TextBox1.text = cesta  ' this variables
    TextBox2.text = cesta2

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() ' 1. field
    
    cesta = TextBox1.Value
     
    If f_FormIsLoaded("form_vyberCesty") Then
        Unload form_vyberCesty
    End If
    'Exit Sub
    
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()  ' 2.field

    cesta = TextBox2.Value
    
    If f_FormIsLoaded("form_vyberCesty") Then
        Unload form_vyberCesty
    End If
    'Exit Sub
    
    
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton3_Click() ' Cancel

    cesta = ""
    
    If f_FormIsLoaded("form_vyberCesty") Then
        Unload form_vyberCesty
    End If
    'Exit Sub

End Sub

I want to pass strings to form and back with local variables , if possible.
Thanks a lot.

It might be a little more advanced, but a good read on the topic of Userform: https://rubberduckvba.blog/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

This is the example form I'm using - it just has TextBox1 and CommandButton1.

The only code in the form hides the form:
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

The code in a normal module:
Sub test1()

    Dim cesta As String  'this variables
    Dim cesta2 As String
    
    cesta = "d:\path1\path2\path3\"
    cesta2 = "d:\path4\path5\path6\"
    
    
    'Create an instance of the form.
    Dim MyForm As form_vyberCesty
    Set MyForm = New form_vyberCesty
    
    'Do stuff with the instance of the form.
    With MyForm
        .TextBox1 = cesta
        'As the ShowModal property is set to True this code will pause while the form is on display.
        .Show
        
        'Once the form is hidden code resumes.
        cesta = .TextBox1
        MsgBox cesta
    End With
    
    'Unload and destroy the instance of the form.
    Unload MyForm
    Set MyForm = Nothing

End Sub

You could also use Property procedures to pass the variables into the form and back again.  The link that @DecimalTurn gave explains it pretty well.

Try to adapt the following code...
[Regular Module]
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim cesta As String
    Dim cesta2 As String
    
    cesta = "d:\path1\path2\path3\"
    cesta2 = "d:\path4\path5\path6\"
    
    If Not form_vyberCesty.ShowForm(cesta, cesta2) Then Exit Sub
    
    MsgBox cesta & vbNewLine & cesta2, vbInformation
    
    'etc
    '
    '
                
End Sub

[UserForm Module]
Option Explicit

Dim proceed As Boolean

Public Function ShowForm(ByRef cesta As String, ByRef cesta2 As String) As Boolean

    TextBox1.Text = cesta
    TextBox2.Text = cesta2
    
    Me.Show
    
    If proceed = False Then
        ShowForm = False
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    cesta = TextBox1.Text
    cesta2 = TextBox2.Text
    
    ShowForm = True
    
End Function

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 'ok button

    proceed = True
    
    Unload Me
    
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 'cancel button

    proceed = False
    
    Unload Me
    
End Sub

